# SQL Server Function return � for especial characters utf-8

Tags: java, sql-server-2005, jdbc, utf-8

I have table with a field called mydata with type nvarchar(max). This contains characters like: é á ñ.
The data is extracted using Java (Spring). The java application is using utf-8 for request and response.

When I execute a simple Select the especial characters show correctly.

```
Select myData from myTable
```

I have simple SQL function which just received a nvarchar and returns it.

```
CREATE function getIt (@mydata nvarchar(max) )
returns nvarchar(max)
as
begin
    return @mydata;
end
```

When I use a function to the especial character don't show and are replace by the � symbol.

```
Select dbo.getIt(myData) as myData from myTable
```

I have test the same process using mySQL and Oracle, in this cases the SQL functions don't change the especial characters.
I am using Tomcat in a Ubuntu Linux box. The database is SQL Sever 2005. I am using JDTS 1.3.

Thank you for your help.

Extra Explanation

If the field myData contains ñ for example, if a execute this:

```
Select
myData,
dbo.getIt(myData) as myData2
from myTable
```

The result of the the columns displayed in the webpage will be ñ ? or ñ �
NVarchar is storgin the data properly but for some reason the function changes something.
If I have a problem with Encoding the ñ will never show properly in both cases.

Comment: Are you 100% sure the data is correct in the database? Where is your output? Where exactly do you see `?` instead of those special characters?

Comment: @jlordo 100% sure the data is correct in the database, the SQL Server Manager Studio displays it properly with and without the function. The out put is a web application, what I see is the ? instead but only when the data is return by the function, otherwise it shows OK in the webpage.

Comment: Can you narrow down the source of the error somehow? E.g. log the value prior to displaying it on the webpage: If it's wrong in the logs you're function is returning it wrong, if it's correct in the logs, your webapp is messing it up. But be careful to implement the logging correct, to avoid a false negative.

Comment: @jlordo While narrowing the problem I got the solution which I am including below. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the problem.

For some reason a regular select to a nvarchar is capture by the JDBO as type (12) VARCHAR.
But the function which also returns a nvarchar is capture as type (-1) LONGVARCHAR.

MySQL and Oracle work in a different way and my Java code was originally for this databases.

The other situation is that nVarchar(400) will return type (12) VARCHAR but nVarchar(MAX) will return type (-1) LONGVARCHAR.

My code was processing all the "LONG" values as binaries and SQL Server enter in this loop.

Thank you @jlordo and @chooban for guiding me to the solution.

Comment: How odd. I'll keep that in mind if I'm ever working with SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

That's the Unicode replacement character. That might occur if you're telling the application to *interpret* the bytes from the database as UTF-8, but *supplying* it with Latin-1 (or another character set). I think that nvarchar means the data is stored as UTF-16, right? I'm not too up on SQL server.

Once you've made the connection to the database, interpret the meta data for the connection and see what character set is being used.

You should also check exactly what's stored in the column. In MySQL, I used a *hex* function to show exactly what bytes are in the field, but I'm not sure what the SQL Server equivalent would be. However, [this page](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/steve_jones/2011/03/25/how-many-bytes-are-in-my-column_3F00_-_1320_-t_2D00_sql-functions/) tells me there are *LEN* and *DATALENGTH* functions which can be used to compare the number of characters with the number of bytes. Finding the equivalent to MySQL's *hex* function is definitely the way to g.